# TypeScript: is it possible to force a generic type in a interface signature that be of the same type of class that implements this interface

Tags: typescript

I want to force a declared generic in a signature of the interface be of the same type of the class that implements this interface. Something like the below code:

```js
interface I1<T = typeof this> {

    aAnyMethod(): I1<T>;

}

class C1 { }

class C2 implements I1<C1> /* accepts C1 but shouldn't, it should only accept C2 */ {

    // ok. It works as it should
    aAnyMethod(): C2 {
        return new C2;
    }

}

class C3 implements I1{

    // not accepted. It works as it should
    aAnyMethod(): C1 {
        return new C1;
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems like you almost want [polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) but that won't let you `return new C2`, as there's no guarantee that this will work for subclasses of `C2`.  Instead you could use explicit F-bounded polymorphism like [this example](https://tsplay.dev/wQ58jw), but it's hard to know if it meets your needs because there are certainly edge cases.  Let me know.

Comment: This almost solves my problem. It doesn't fully resolve because the `T extends ...` statement creates a covariance. If `C1` implements interface `I1`, `C2 implements I1<C1>` becomes acceptable, but it shouldn't, it must strictly accept `I1<C2>`.

Comment: Can you explain your use case by showing some code where it matters?  I don't think it's possible to write a generic type `I<T>` wherein `X extends I<Y>` if and only if `Y` and `X` are identical.  Clearly if `X extends I<X>` and `interface Z extends X {somethingElse: string}` then `Z extends I<X>` is also true, but `X` and `Z` are not identical types; there's covariance there by definition.  So it seems hopeless from the start unless I'm misunderstanding your requirement. If you show a use case where it matters, maybe there's an alternative approach that will meet that need better.

Comment: Again, for what it's worth, polymorphic `this` is the "right" way to do this, but subclass hierarchies really make your particular implementation impossible (or at least unsafe and requiring type assertions); see [this example](https://tsplay.dev/N54Pdw).   Usually you'd only use polymorphic `this` for dealing with the current instance and not some other instance of the same class.

Comment: I'd want to write a generic interface that implements the Prototype design pattern.

Comment: So then like [this example](https://tsplay.dev/mZr4Dm) using polymorphic `this`?  If you want I can write up an answer talking about `this` types, since that's essentially the feature you want.

Comment: Yeap. Exactly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can give the type parameter a self-referential upper bound. This is a standard solution to this problem, used e.g. in Java's interface [`Comparable<T extends Comparable<T>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

```
interface MyInterface<T extends MyInterface<T>> {
    someMethod(): T;
}

class Works implements MyInterface<Works> {
    someMethod() { return new Works(); }
    foo() { return 'foo'; }
}

// error: Type 'SomethingElse' does not satisfy the constraint 'MyInterface<SomethingElse>'.
class DoesntWork implements MyInterface<SomethingElse> {
    someMethod() { return new SomethingElse(); }
}
```

Unfortunately, something like this will still work:

```
// No error, because Works extends MyInterface<Works>
class ShouldntWorkButDoes implements MyInterface<Works> {
    someMethod() { return new Works(); }
    baz() { return 'baz'; }
}
```

However, this doesn't cause a problem because anywhere you want to accept something implementing `MyInterface`, you can require that it implement `MyInterface<...>` of itself:

```
function acceptsMyInterface<T extends MyInterface<T>>(arg: T) {}

// OK
acceptsMyInterface(new Works());

// error: Argument of type 'ShouldntWorkButDoes' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyInterface<ShouldntWorkButDoes>'.
acceptsMyInterface(new ShouldntWorkButDoes());
```

So then `ShouldntWorkButDoes` only works where it is declared, not where it is used. (Note that for the purpose of this demonstration, I had to add some members `foo` and `baz` so that Typescript doesn't treat these types as [structurally equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).)

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-a244hkCjytM4giENgyPpNFbBDjs+YAeQA0lwkxAU9Rc64IDJPcr5HI1FwOdA+UoAIJQJrhc3IAQwR5rDbqgSa7VgJL6w0Iw63GIXRMGYBNEBwbq2R48qx9ODbaDjydgaejZs22fznVmZdGzyQusIZOpq151ueh9ak+pgvginZqEAA)

Comment: Yes. Thanks. But this almost solves my problem. It doesn't fully resolve because the `T extends ...` statement creates a covariance. If `C1` implements interface `I1`, `C2 implements I1<C1>` becomes acceptable, but it shouldn't, it must strictly accept `I1<C2>`.

Comment: @rplaurindo As I wrote in my answer (see `ShouldntWorkButDoes`), that works where `C2` is declared, but not where `C2` is used. Ultimately you cannot forbid other classes from implementing `I1<C1>` because `I1<C1>` is an interface and as far as Typescript is concerned, classes are allowed to implement interfaces; but you can still enforce the requirement whereever things of type `I1<...>` are used.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanks.